# Create the table without a Primary Key. openpyxl to sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, openpyxl

So here I am sorting from an excel file using openpyxl to then move the data into a sqlite database.. So I have sorted it by creating a dictionary and using the serial number as the primary key... Unfortunately, this is wrong as there shouldn't be any primary key in my table.. how do I change this so I get all the values even if they duplicate

```
 violations_lookup = {}
 skip_row = True
 for row in 
 violations_sheet_obj.iter_rows('A{}:E{}'.format(violations_sheet_obj.min_row, 
 violations_sheet_obj.max_row)):
     if not skip_row:
         points, serial_number, violation_code, violation_description, 
 violation_status = [cell.value for cell in row[:]]
         violations_lookup[serial_number] = (
             serial_number, points, violation_code, violation_description, 
 violation_status
         )
     else:
         skip_row = False

 violations_data = list(violations_lookup.values())
```

Comment: Just don't have a primary key column when creating your table?

Comment: Just export to SQLite and sort there.